# Date diff timorrow date

Tags: php, datetime

I have date

```
object(DateTime)[44]
  public 'date' => string '1980-11-21 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)

/srv/www/vhosts/drevlanka.ru/work/support/functions.inc.php:3109:
object(DateTime)[48]
  public 'date' => string '2019-11-20 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Moscow' (length=13)
```

And code

```
    $interval = $dateTwo->diff($birthdate);
      //  $interval = $birthdate->diff($dateTwo);
        var_dump($interval);
```

if `$bistdate<$dateTwo`, i have current interval, but if `$bistdate>$dateTwo` this function return incorrect days diff.

Comment: What's your mean by `incorrect days diff`

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. Try for yourself: https://3v4l.org/PjDrq

Comment: Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58971768/6521116)